# PHP regex: how to get value in one line of code?

Tags: php, regex

The question is how to get value from `preg_match()` function the shortest way possible.

Let say, I know my string ends with digits. I'm sure! 100%!! Its in stone!!!
What I need, is the value...

So far I do

```
preg_match('/(\d+)$/', $mystring, $m);
echo $m[1];
```

Is there a way to do this in one line of code?

I tried:

```
echo preg_match('/(\d+)$/', $mystring, $m)[1];
```

Error returned....

Any ideas?

Comment: The `myFunction()[index]` syntax is available in PHP 5.4: http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php

Comment: @WesleyMurch +1 but that still wont work for the askers example since `preg_match` returns an int.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/preg_replace) instead:

```
echo preg_replace('/^.*?(\d+)$/', '$1', $str);
```

**Explanation:**

- `^` - assert position at the start of the string
- `.*?` - match any character (except newline characters)
- `\d+` - match (and capture) one or more digits
- `$` - assert position at the end of the string
- `$1` - the contents captured by the first capturing group

Comment: Erroneous comment removed. Nice job +1

Answer (score 4):

Not that I'm advocating this, but in this particular case, you could do it this way:

```
echo $m[preg_match('/(\d+)$/', $mystring, $m)];
```

It's too convoluted and brittle to put in maintainable source, but I thought it was an interesting example of pointers and reference passing, so I wanted to put it up here.  It relies on there being exactly one match (which is guaranteed by `preg_match`, but not `preg_match_all`), and the desired text being in the first group, but it works.

http://ideone.com/eWZoCD